# Getting an index from an array and converting it

Tags: java, arrays

I am a novice programmer and stuck for ages. I have got an array of strings and wanted to get hold of the last word after splitting it into 5 words and also converting it to a interger as its an array of strings. This is what I have tried out but its not close to working. Please how do I do this? :(. Thanks

```
    String FailSome = "Tests run: 12,  Failures: 4";

    String[] words = FailSome.split("\\s+");

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
       Integer.parseInt(words[4]);
       System.out.println(words[i]);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope,
as i understood that you want to split FailSome,

store in String array and want to convert the last value of the to array to int,

then display it

I hope this will work for you,

```
String FailSome = "Tests run: 12,  Failures: 4";
String[] words = FailSome.split("\\s");//splitting goes here
int lastindexofarray=(words.length)-1;
int value=Integer.parseInt(words[lastindexofarray]);
System.out.println(value);//if you want to print the converted value
```

Output : 4

thanks

Comment: Thank you very much. That was easy to understand and it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider a better approach, if your pattern is fixed, you can use the following regex:

```
\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)
```

Or simple `\d+` and print the second match..

Now the result you want is available in the first captured group.

You don't need the `for` loop in your example, remove it and you'll be fine.

Comment: the fourth element is "Failures:"

Comment: OP wants the last word. It's `words[4]`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but I couldnt get it to work with this :( but I have found an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

To get "last word":

```
    String FailSome = "Tests run: 12,  Failures: 4";
    int failures = Integer.parseInt(FailSome.split("Failures:\\s")[1]);
    System.out.println(failures);
```